# Issues with dismiss keyboard using Tap Gesture when UITextField is inside UIScrollView.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I designed an App that have the follow hierarchy:

```
UIViewController
  UIView
    UIScrollView
      UITextField
```

On the ViewDidLoad I did:

```
...
tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
...
```

On the hideKeyboard I did:

```
- (void) hideKeyboard {
    //Hide keyBoard
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

At first glance, it works perfectly, but unfortunately there is a problem.
When the application is running, we can click UITextField that the keyboard is shown as expected. If we click out side UITextField, the method `hideKeyboard` is called and dismiss the keyboard as expected, but if you try to click again UITextField the keyboard is not shown again.

What I doing wrong? Anyone know?

Comment: When you tap the text field in the second time is the method `hideKeyboard` called again?

Comment: Yes @Hejazi, the method is called again.

Comment: Well, try adding this condition before hiding the keyboard: `if (![textField pointInside:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:textField] withEvent:nil]) { //Hide keyboard }`

Comment: @Hejazi I was studying my code again and find the reason for this behaviour. Unfortunately I forgot an old code used when we don't use UIScrollView. The code inside the method textFieldDidBeginEditing: (protocol of UITextFieldDelegate) was dismiss the keyboard after the first click. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very general issue to deal with each time when user feedback is required. It will be very helpful if apple include such day-to-day features in up coming framework releases.

There are a hundred and one proposed solutions out there for how to move UITextField and UITextView out of the way of the keyboard during editing — usually, it comes down to observing

1. UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, or
2. Implementing UITextFieldDelegate delegate methods, and adjusting the frame of the superview, or
3. Using UITableView‘s scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

But all the proposed solutions I’ve found tend to be quite DIY, and have to be implemented for each view controller that needs it.

Solution courtesy of Michael Tyson...
**A drop-in universal solution for moving text fields out of the way of the keyboard** 
You can grab the source files, which includes a sample project, over on the [GitHub project page.](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Comment: Cool @alloc_iNit, but the problem already was solved. The main problem was in the textFieldDidBeginEditing: protocol working together Tap Gestures. The first was sabotaging the second one. Anyway, thanks by your time.

Comment: @GabrielLopes - Yep, the only purpose to share the handy solution and get rid off same logical code lines and save development time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
- (void) hideKeyboard 
{
    //Hide keyBoard
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.scrollView bringSubViewToFront:YourTextField];
}
```

Comment: Well thought @Tapas Pal, but doesn't worked. The apps keeps accepting just the first click.

Comment: I was studying my code again and find the reason for this behavior. Unfortunately I forgot an old code used when we don't use UIScrollView. The code inside the method textFieldDidBeginEditing: (protocol of UITextFieldDelegate) was dismiss the keyboard after the first click. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I once wanted to detect touches on the scrollview similar to touches on the UIView.

To access the touches on the scrollview like touches began and touches ended and other such methods I subclassed the UIScrollView and I am able to access all the touch events on the scrollview.

Try doing that if you want to access touch event on UIView as well as UIScrollView.